# Multilabel Classification using NaiveBayes Classifier in Spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-mllib, naivebayes

I have the data in the format
`blah sentence one   -->  label1, label2`
`blah sentence two   -->  label2, label4`
`blah sentence three -->  label3`

How can I use OneVsRestClassifier with NaiveBayesClassifier in Spark?
(i.e., How should my data be structured?).
For a multi-class classification with NaiveBayes, the class `LabeledPoint` contains `label` and `Feature Vector`. But, for the above mentioned case, how should the data be structured?

Answer (score 0):

Just structure the data as usual (LabeledPoint), but use *multiple* classifiers (e.g, OneVsRest), and switch up the data passed into each (based on your multiple labelled vectors).
Another solution is to get the probabilities for all classes, instead of getting the most probable (predict(p.features()))

```
Vector prediction = model.predictProbabilities(p.features());
```

and then take the topk most probable predictions using a threshold filtering.